# How to duplicate iOS target with different configuration and resources in a swift project

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am trying to create a clone of an existing iOS swift app with slightly different configuration (label, bundle, app icon, etc.).  I tried many different approaches and it seems that the best one is simply to create a new target from the existing one by duplicating and modifying it. When I do that I want to use the original Storyboard. However when I run the app with the new target I always get the following exception:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key...**

which I believe happens because of the references in the outlets. Is it even possible to use the same Storyboard file from another targets? I also tried to create a completely new target that uses the existing Storyboard, but somehow the target cannot find it.

---

**Edit 30.07.2015**

The same error appears when I just rename the project. Somehow the referenced IBOutlets in the storyboard cannot be found, although they are present and correctly linked

Comment: Go to `Project` under `Targets`, Right click your `Project` and select `Duplicate` . Then rename your new target, so that you can distinguish easily.

Comment: That is precisely what I've done. I tried it on a new test project and there everything works fine, but when I do it with the existing one I always get the described error.